# Non-linear "forward" button in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, history

#### Short version

Can I modify the `forward`-button in Firefox to access multiple different forward-locations?

#### Problem description

Suppose I am currently visiting website `A`. Now, I perform the following sequence of actions:

- visit website `B`
- click the `back` button in the navigation toolbar to get back to `A`
- visit website `C`
- click the `back` button to get back to `A` again

This browsing behavior creates some kind of tree where `A` is the root and `B`, `C` are nodes on the same depth.
Now, the `forward` button only enables me to visit website `C`. Accessing `B` is not longer possible, since the forward button only keeps a *linear* history.

#### Question

Is there any way to allow me to visit the whole tree of `forward` pages? Like a dropdown menu for the `forward` button (when currently visiting `A`), that shows all the visited locations of the next depth level in my tree:

```
A - C
  - B
```

Comment: Have you try to use history option in FF? It's not back and forward but you will see site B

Comment: @RomeoNinov I will see site B, but it will be mixed with all the other sites I have visited. I actively use >20 tabs at the same time, so my history contains a lot of recently visited sites. The nice thing about `forward` and `back` is, that it is ordered and individual for each tab

Comment: A simple search for “firefox history tree” listed this: [Session History Tree](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/session-history-tree/). Could be what you’re looking for.

Comment: Can't you right-click (or press and hold) on the Forward/Back buttons, to see a history either way?  You can in Chrome and IE.

Comment: @paradroid It does show a history, but it is **linear**. I can see the last few pages and the next "forward" pages of the last taken branch. For my example, I could see `C` and `C'`, but all that belonged to `B` is pruned

Comment: @DanielB Thanks! This is pretty close to what I am looking for. Can't believe that I didn't find this after all my search. It has some GUI annoyances (could be its own button, could give the tree-view also to the history), but it is not bad and does solve my problem. I will wait for other replies, but fee free to post your answer, so I can award you the bounty in case no better solutions are posted.

Comment: Any particular reason why you can't just have `A`, `B` and `C` in different windows or tabs?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling No, there is no reason why I couldn't do it with tabs (in fact, that's what I usually do). This is more a matter of "I think it should be possible, so I want to see if it has been done properly" than an urgent need on my side. Otherwise, I would have asked this question years ago or implemented it myself ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Google search for “firefox history tree” lead me to this Firefox Extension: [Session History Tree](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/session-history-tree/). I haven’t tried it myself but it could be what you’re looking for.

[image]

[image]

(Images taken from AMO)

Unfortunately, it seems this extension is no longer maintained, the last commit on the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/ddawson/Session-History-Tree/) was almost two years ago.

Comment: The addon feels a bit clunky to use (it is hidden 1 layer behind the regular `back` button) and would do well with a LITTLE added functionality. But it appears stable and is still working well. So maybe it is still maintained, but considered "feature complete"...

Comment: Anyway: This is good and pretty much what I was looking for. Enjoy the bounty!

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of add-ons that can help :

[**History in Threads**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/history-in-threads/) (last update March 8, 2015)

[image: image1]

---

[FromWhereToWhere](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/fromwheretowhere/) (last update May 5, 2014)

[image: image2]

Comment: These addons are helpful indeed. Unfortunately not exactly what I was looking for. Thanks anyway!